# UIButton inside UITableViewCell slides in from side when animating UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I'd like to have a slide in from bottom animation on my UITableview when the View appears. So inside the viewDidAppear Methode I created the following Animation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f       // for testing purposes big value
                          delay:0.0f
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.7f    // 0...1
          initialSpringVelocity:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         [tv_team setAlpha:1.0f];
                         tv_teamsVerticalConstraint.constant = 0;

                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }
     ];
```

that works perfectly fine for the UITableView itself, however I dynamically add labels and buttons to each UITableViewCell like so

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"teamCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    //if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    //}

    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[[ColorSchema sharedColorSchema] color_background]];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    UIView *vw_centered = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 70)];
    vw_centered.autoresizingMask = (
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
                                    );
    [vw_centered setBackgroundColor:[[ColorSchema sharedColorSchema] color_darkerbackground]];
    [vw_centered.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [vw_centered setTag:1];

    //... more Labels

 // Button to change the teamMembers
    UIButton *btn_setPlayers = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn_setPlayers.frame = CGRectMake(340.0, 39.0, 120.0, 19.0);
    [btn_setPlayers setBackgroundColor:[[ColorSchema sharedColorSchema] color_darkgray]];
    [btn_setPlayers setTag:indexPath.row];
    [btn_setPlayers.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:9.0]];
    [btn_setPlayers setTitleColor:[[ColorSchema sharedColorSchema] color_orangeSolid] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_setPlayers setTitle:@"Change Team Members" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_setPlayers addTarget:self action:@selector(changeTeamMembers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn_setPlayers.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [vw_centered addSubview:btn_setPlayers];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:vw_centered];

    return cell;
}
```

problem is, that the created button slides in from the left until it reaches the frame location on the second, third, ... cell (not the first - probably because thats the prototype cell)

How can I stop that animation?

[image]

im running xcode 6 ios 8.1

Comment: Hi. I've a made a simple project with your code and didn't see it. It may be something with the initial size of the cell. I recommend you to make a custom cell with a nib with all the inner views, and use autolayout. It is much cleaner and prevents bugs, in addition you can set properties like color and style, in the 'awakeFromNib' one time only. give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid unwanted animations by wrapping the changes in `performWithoutAnimation`:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    // changes
}];
```

So try setting your button's frame in one of these.

Comment: if i wrap the frame settings into that, the button itself is set at the right position but now the title is animated (enlarge from center), if I also put the set title setting into that wrapper nothing changes, still enlarging from the center

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure whats going on, but I'd try `[btn_setPlayers layoutIfNeeded]` after setting the button frame.

Comment: I agree with the commenter who suggested setting up the cell in Interface Builder and Auto Layout.